# How to delete pod immediately?

Tags: java, kubernetes

I want to force delete a `pod` immediately by using `io.kubernetes:ClientJavaApi`.

I tried to use the following command to delete, but there is still a delay

```
options = new V1DeleteOptions();
options.setGracePeriodSeconds(0L);
options.setPropagationPolicy("Foreground");
options.setOrphanDependents(false);

V1Pod result = coreV1Api.deleteNamespacedPod(name, namespace, "true", null,
                    gracePeriodSeconds, null, null, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
V1DeleteOptions v1DeleteOptions = new V1DeleteOptions();
v1DeleteOptions.setGracePeriodSeconds(0L);
V1Pod deleteNamespacedPod = coreV1Api.deleteNamespacedPod(
        podName,
        namespace,
        null,
        "false",
        0,
        true,
        null,
        v1DeleteOptions);
```